# How to add common code in a scala Trait's method

Tags: scala

```
trait T {
  def f(x: String): String
}

class A {
  override def f(x: String) = customMethodA(x.trim.toLowerCase)
} extends T

class B {
  override def f(x: String) = customMethodB(x.trim.toLowerCase)
} extends T
```

In the example above, the parameter `x` goes through the same transformation in all the implementations of `f`. Is there a way to add the transformation in the trait `T`'s `f` itself so it doesn't need to be repeated in `A`'s and `B`'s `f`?

Comment: Why not just put the implementation inside trait T?

Comment: @texasbruce because the overall implementation of `f` might differ across the implementation classes

Comment: You have to override them anyway if you don't provide implementation in the base trait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make that method final and delegate its implementation to a protected abstract method like this:

```scala
trait T {
  final def f(x: String): String =
    fImpl(x.trim.toLowerCase)
  
  protected def fImpl(x: String): String
}

final class A extends T {
  override def fImpl(x: String): String =
    customMethodA(x)
}

final class B extends T  {
  override def fImpl(x: String): String =
    customMethodB(x)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping that there would be a way which wouldn't require creating 2 times as many methods in the trait, but I guess this is as good as it gets?

Comment: @NitinYadav there is not automatic way AFAIK, you may want a macro or something to generate the redundant methods but it would just be more complex and make the code harder to read just to save some copy and paste.